# Running behind a proxy server

Tags: docker, proxy, gitlab-ci-runner, http-proxy, gitlab-ce

I want to run my GitLab runner behind a proxy server and I have already installed cntlm and config it with my proxy server
the next step I'm trying to do is configure docker HTTP/HTTPS proxy variables as above:

```
  [Service] 
  Environment=“HTTP_PROXY=http://*.*.*.*:port”
  Environment=“HTTPS_PROXY=https://*.*.*.*:port”
  Environment=“NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1”
```

My first question is what should I put in **port**?
Should it be my proxy server port or 80/443 or 3128?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was running above command line:

```
gitlab-runner run
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running with a local proxy, then the port should be 3128.

It is from that port the local proxy will redirect to the actual NTLM proxy.

I have been using [`nrwl/nx`](https://github.com/nrwl/nx) for years, with as environment variables:

```sh
HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128
HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128
```